# Comparing char with a variable string

Tags: c++

I am a newbie to C++, with TC as my compiler.(Yes I know it's old, but it's what I have to use for my studies.)

I'm having a problem understanding comparison of char[].
This is my code.

```
char chi[3];


void input1()
{
int xtemp,ytemp;
gotoxy(60,2);
cout<<"Enter which piece you";gotoxy(60,3);cout<<"would like to select.";gotoxy(60,4);cout<<"(Eg.a1,a2,a3.):";
cin>>chi;
if(chi=="a1"){xtemp=0;ytemp=0;}
if(chi=="a2"){xtemp=1;ytemp=0;}
if(chi=="a3"){xtemp=2;ytemp=0;}
//.....
if(chi=="h7"){xtemp=6;ytemp=7;}
if(chi=="h8"){xtemp=7;ytemp=7;}
cout<<xtemp<<ytemp;
getch();


}
```

Everytime I run my program, of which this function is a part of, I try cin values liek a1,a2,g8,etc. However, my cout statement always shows 99. Excuse me for my ignorance. Thanks in advance! :)

-CaptainAwesome

Comment: Even outdated Turbo C++ provides a debugger letting inspect you, what's actually going on.

Comment: You can't `==` on character arrays (unless you just want to compare address). You need to use the C string functions, which they apparently have not taught you yet. *Or*, you could enter the modern world and use a relatively new compiler and use `std::string`, which *does* have a `==`.

Comment: The main problem with TurboC++ is not "just" the age, but that it missed many things which were invented later and/or changed in the language specs. Do yourself a favour and download GCC now.

Comment: If i'm not mistaken, comparing a table with a string literal, will probably compare the address of the first element of this table with the address of the literal in the data segment, try using strcmp. (Edit: wow too slow)

Comment: As others mentioned, you need to download a modern compiler.  [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org) or [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org) are available for most platforms, including Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Since `"a1"` is a pointer to a constant, `if(chi=="a1")` asks if `chi` points to this same constant. Since `chi` is an array whose contents can be modified and not a pointer to anything constant, this will never be true. Did you want to compare two strings? If so, you want to use a function like `strcmp` that compares strings.

Answer (score 2):

`chi== "a1"` is a pointer comparison and will always give false.
To check for string equality you need `strcmp(chi,"a1") == 0`